# Titanium Removing child perfomance issue

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

I have been developing an app using Titanium. I have a scrollview and i am trying to remove childs like below.

**First**

```
scrollview.removeAllChildren();
```

but there is another way to remove the subview by looping the scrollview children like below,

**Second**

```
for (var x = 0; x < scrollview.children; x++) {
   var child = scrollview.childAt(x);
   scrollview.remove(child);
}
```

My question is which of the above method is good to use when it come to performance wise?

When we deletes child using second method we can visually see the performance. but some suggests second method is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

How much time difference are you observing between the two calls in the worst case scenario (where your scrollview might have hundreds of UI elements). Also you can look into the native implementation in the framework and decide on which is better suited for you. But generally, this first method should be good in most of the cases (also it looks clean)